# Error: compilation of \cimgnbmap_lower.cpp failed

Tags: matlab, mex, toolbox

> > I am using a Matlab code for multiscale image segmentation writtern by Timothee Cour (INRIA), Stella Yu (Boston College), Jianbo Shi
> >     (UPENN) (c) 2004 University of Pennsylvania, Computer and Information
> >     Science Department.
>
> from
>
> [> http://timotheecour.com/software/ncut_multiscale/ncut_multiscale.html](http://timotheecour.com/software/ncut_multiscale/ncut_multiscale.html)
>
> when I tried to run CompileDir function I faced this error:
>
> I am using Matlab R2013a
>
> > compileDir
> >         You can change your home, image, and results directories if you want ; see startup/definePaths
> >         *********************************
> >         Error: compilation of \cimgnbmap_lower.cpp failed :     Usage:
> >                 MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
> >                     [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

```
    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_XindicatorTimesX.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_affinity_option.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_computeRowSum.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_constraint_classes.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_extractMaxima.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_istril.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_neighborW.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_normalizeColumns.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_projection_QR_symmetric.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \mex_w_times_x_symmetric_tril.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
Error: compilation of \spmtimesd.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.



There were 0 files compiled

Error: There were 12 erroneous files during compilation
\cimgnbmap_lower.cpp
\mex_XindicatorTimesX.cpp
\mex_affinity_option.cpp
\mex_computeRowSum.cpp
\mex_constraint_classes.cpp
\mex_extractMaxima.cpp
\mex_istril.cpp
\mex_neighborW.cpp
\mex_normalizeColumns.cpp
\mex_projection_QR_symmetric.cpp
\mex_w_times_x_symmetric_tril.cpp
\spmtimesd.cpp

ans = 

1x12 struct array with fields:

    isErrorDuringCompilation
    isCompilationFailed
    message
    compiledFilename
    file
    isError

>>
```

Comment: post your command please

Comment: My command was exactly as it was  mentioned in the help document:

Comment: Running the scripts
1) Unzip the files to some directory mydir
2) In matlab, type:
cd mydir
init
compileDir //only need to be run once to compile mex-files

Comment: compileDir //only need to be run once to compile mex-files

Comment: compileDir is a function that has been written by authors and it will call another function named (compileFiles)

Comment: In that webpage it says.  "Note: if you are using AMD 64 and comileDir brings errors, this might be due to a bug in gcc. The following should fix it: edit the config file for compiling matlab mex files. It is typically located under: /home/username/.matlab/R14SP3/mexopts.sh. Go to the section glnxa64, and replace the optimization flag -O with -O2: 
           COPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG' 
           CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'". Have you done exactly what it says??

Comment: I am not using AMD 64 .

Comment: I think that matlab does not recognize any compiler and that is why I faced that error , because I wrote this command: mex -v and I faced this error : 
 
  Error: Could not find the compiler "cl" on the DOS path. 
         Use mex -setup to configure your environment properly. 
 
 
  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unable to locate compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Matlab R2015a, the problem solved.